# Cast Map<String, ? extends Object> to Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, generics, casting

In Java 8, I am trying to cast `Map<String, ? extends Object>` to `Map<String, Object>`. I though that it would be safe given the constraint I put on the input Type (all ? must implement Object), but I get an unchecked cast warning.

Any idea where I reason wrong ? Any clean solution ? Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cast is not safe. In particular:

```
Map<String, ? extends Object> before;
before.put("foo", "example"); // <-- illegal

Map<String, Object> after;
after.put("foo", "example"); // <-- legal
```

Observe that `String` is not a subclass of `? extends Object` because you don't know `?` but it is a subclass of the more general `Object` thus the second call is okay.

Comment: Thank you @WorldSEnder, the use case I am trying to work out is setting a member variable of type `Map<String, Object>` using an argument of type `Map<String, String>`. And just affecting the member to the argument is not possible as I assume that `Map<String, Object>` is not related to `Map<String, String>`... can't figure out the clean path out of it now...

Comment: @Antonin you could make the containing clas generic and the field type `Map<String, T>` with the generic parameter `T`

Comment: Thanks @WorldSEnder, unfortunately, that would induce too many changes in client code. I guess I'll have to find another way.